# How to check hex flags in PHP?

Tags: php

I've written a little web application to monitor the version of my bigger releases and now I've decided to send some information in the form of hex flags like 000000000000C19B. The mysql db field is a utf8 (16)varchar.

In the php script I have an array from 0x800000 to 0x01.

```
$gFlagsLong = array( 0x800000 => "Reserv6", //24
                0x400000 => "Reserve5", //23
                0x200000 => "Flag22",   //22
                0x100000 => "Flag21",   //21
                0x80000 => "Flag20",    //20
                0x40000 => "Flag19",    //19
                0x20000 => "Flag18",    //18
                0x10000 => "Flag17",    //17
                0x8000 => "Flag16",     //16
                0x4000 => "Flag15",     //15
                0x2000 => "Flag14",     //14
                0x1000 => "Flag13",     //13
                0x800 => "Flag12",      //12
                0x400 => "Reserve2",    //11
                0x200 => "Flag10",  //10
                0x100 => "Flag9",       //9
                0x80 => "Reserve1",     //8
                0x40 => "Flag7",        //7
                0x20 => "Flag6",        //6 
                0x10 => "Flag5",        //5
                0x08 => "Flag4",        //4
                0x04 => "Flag3",        //3
                0x02 => "Flag2",        //2
                0x01 => "Flag1" );      //1
```

And I try, like in C, to che flags string if any of the values is set.

```
                $sFlags ="000000000000C19B";
                $sCheck = "X";
                $sNCheck = "&#32;"; // html space char  
                $sTemp = "";
                foreach($gFlagsLong as  $nKey => $sBez){
                    if($sFlags & $nKey) $sTemp = $sCheck;
                    else $sTemp = $sNCheck;
                    echo "<td id='flag' title='" . $sBez . "'>"  . $sTemp . "</td>";
                }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work correctly. The code works but the bitwise AND doesnt seem to be correct here. I get false positives and false negatives. 
I googled a bit but to be honest I don't know exactly what I should gfoogle for. PHP isn't my strongest field.
I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: "Unfortunately it doesn't work correctl" isn't a problem description anybody can work with.

Comment: Yep, your actual question here is unclear. Certainly you can use a bitwise AND operator in php. But it is unclear what your code is actually meant to do.

Comment: Sorry, I thought with the given information is enough.
Well, the code works but the bitwise AND doesnt seem to be correct here. I get false positives and false negatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bitwise AND works with integers, you are trying to use it on a string.

Change $sFlags to `$sFlags = 0x000000000000C19B;` in your test.

`UNHEX(flags)` when you select them from mysql

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the missing piece of the puzzle. However, I  get the flags from the mysqli result rows and I couldn't find a place for UNHEX.
But I prepend 0x to the string and use hexdec in the PHP script. This works fine, too.